# Laravel - Catch specific public folder route

Tags: laravel, routes

Sorry if this sounds so basic.

I've encoutered a scenario where I need to add certain checks when user access certain file in public folder.

<strike>With default setting, you can access specific file in public directory directly by typing its url in the browser:</strike> Sorry this is misleading. 
You can access an image with:

```
localhost/img/banner.jpg
```

But I can't catch it with:

```html
Route::get('/img/banner.jpg', function(){
  //checks goes here
});
```

How it should be done?

Comment: the webserver checks for files and folders matching the URI first, then hands off to Laravel (`index.php`) .. with the "default" configurations Laravel is a fallback

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki isn't it? you can access anything within the public folder just by typing the file with fresh laravel install? I refer it "default setting", I don't tamper with middleware, route or htaccess to public folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create controller for serve images(files) and disallow direct access if you need control. On example:

```
Route::get('/file/{name}', function ($name) {
    // Your check and return file with correct response headers 
}
```

Or best way to create controller for that.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem . Check laravel Docs to see how manage multiple file storages.

Answer (score 1):

I just found another way without using filesystem.

In .htaccess inside public folder, add these:

```
RewriteCond \banner.jpg$ !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Which will let laravel handle the route then I can catch it with:

```
Route::get('/img/banner.jpg', function(){
  //checks goes here
});
```